# R - nested aggregate

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a table d1 like this (three columns, JB Y and P)

```
JB  Y   P
AA  11  1
BB  11  2
AA  12  3
BB  12  4
AA  13  3
CC  12  4
CC  13  2
DD  11  1
DD  12  1
DD  13  3
BB  12  3
```

and what I am trying to do is is get nested aggregate. I mean the result should like this:

```
JB  Y   Avergare (P)
AA  11  1
AA  12  2
AA  13  3
BB  11  2
BB  12  3.5
CC  12  4
CC  13  2
DD  11  1
DD  12  1
DD  13  3
```

The nested aggregate first aggregates using Y and than JB and provides mean P? Not sure if possible. I know how to get just simple aggregate but wonder if there is a way to analyse data in two (or more steps)

Comment: Do you mean you want `mean(P)` for each unique combination of `JB` and `Y`? If so, then using the `dplyr` package do `library(dplyr)` then `d1 %>% group_by(JB, Y) %>% summarise(Avergare = mean(P))`.

Comment: `aggregate(P ~ JB + Y, mydf, mean)`? Why is the second "AA" value 2 in your output? Is that a typo?

Comment: If there are two similar data.table solutions, I don't understand why somebody who posted earlier is not considered.

Comment: above code did not work i am afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
    JB = c("AA", "BB", "AA", "BB", "AA", "CC", "CC", "DD", "DD", "DD", "BB"),
    Y = c(11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 12, 13, 11, 12, 13, 12),
    P = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3))

dt[order(JB), .(avg = mean(P)), by = .(JB, Y)]
```

The `.()` in the middle is used to name the aggregation result. If ordering is not necessary, you may omit the first part, e.g. just call
`dt[, .(avg = mean(P)), by = .(JB, Y)]`.

Comment: Thank you. It work like magic. I used CSV file and amended your code and it is the one I was after.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(P= mean(P)) , .(JB, Y)]
```

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, this is a vanilla `aggregate` problem, so you have lots of tools available.

In base R, the obvious candidate is `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(P ~ JB + Y, mydf, mean)
```

You can also use the "dplyr" package, as suggested by @eipi10, if that is more your style:

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% group_by(JB, Y) %>% summarise(P = mean(P))
```